# PHP, how do I find if a word is in my string?

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried using `\/b` and `[[:<:]]`, not sure why they don't work. And `%` only works if it's at the very beginning of the string.

In my category table I have strings like :

```
Race car driver
Driving Instructor
```

In the search box, if the user types `'driv'` (not case sensitive), I want both of the strings above to appear.

```
//if a person arrives at this page other than doing a search then go to the main page
if(!isset($_POST['search'])) {
    header("Location:mainpage.php");
}

$search_sql="SELECT * FROM category WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND cat_name LIKE '[[:<:]]".$_POST['search']."%'";

$search_query=mysqli_query($con,$search_sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query)!=0) {
$search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}

if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query)!=0) {

    do { ?>
    <p><?php echo $search_rs['cat_name']; ?></p>

    etc... etc ...
```

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't recognise regexp. If yu want to use regexp, use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: wrap the Query with "%". I meant put "%" in the beginning and at the end of the Query

Comment: @AbdullahMallik If I do that it will recognise any words or parts of words in the string. For example, 'riv' would return both 'Race Car Driver' and 'Driving Instructor'. It should only be the beginning of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
".. cat_name LIKE '".$_POST['search']."%' or cat_name LIKE '% ".$_POST['search']."%'";
```

So it's either a first word or it has at least one space in front.